# String from json appears fine with js eval() but has weird characters when I decode it in php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a json file:

[LINK TO JSON PAGE](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=1&q=http://www.emea.gr/feed)

When I decode it with js eval I get the content with links etc.

But when I try to decode it using php I get some weird characters.

To see what I mean just paste the content of the JSON file here: [ONLINE JSON PARSER](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and then as you can see on your left hand there are 2 types of decode (1)string parse and (2)js eval.

PHP decode outputs string like the (1)string parse. I need to decode it like js eval does BUT in php.... Any ideas?

Comment: don't use eval(), it sort-of-kind-of does JSON, but really it just tries to parse (potentially not JSON) javascript. Browsers (and nodejs etc) come with `JSON.parse()` to parse json-serialized string data, and `JSON.stringify()` to turn objects into json strings. Use that, and see if it still passes. Good chance that JSON.parse will flag it as erroneous too

Comment: This will be an issue with string encoding, the PHP `json_decode` function supports UTF-8 and it looks like the data Google sends is UTF-8, but perhaps there is something to look into here.

Comment: can you send a snippet of what you have done/tried?